# How to use tabhost and tabwidget in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to use tabhost and tabwidget inside fragment with swipe left to right and vice verse.
I have only one Activity (for container i use FrameLayout) and drawer navigation,navigation drawer have 5 item linked with 5 fragments. In 2 of these fragments i want to use tabs with swipe with good animations (like in Activity).
For now the tabs doesn't look nice and i can't customize them.
Here is my realization of fragments:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

```
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (id == R.id.nav_feed) {

        fragment = new FeedFragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_file) {
        fragment = new FileFragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_image) {
        fragment = new ImageFragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        fragment = new ShareFragment();

    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }
    return true;
}
```

And here my Fragment where i wanna use tabs with swipe:

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

public FeedFragment() {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.fragment_feed);

    Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
    arg1.putInt("arg for News", 1);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("News"),
            FeedNewsFragment.class, arg1);

    Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
    arg2.putInt("arg for My", 2);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("My"),
            FeedMyFragment.class, arg2);

    return mTabHost;
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mTabHost = null;
}
```

Its working but i can't use the swipe.

I'm new to java and this is my first project so please bear with me.

Comment: In order to swipe between tabs you need to use `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`. That way you will get desired behavior

Comment: I try this:

ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new FeedPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
But it not work.